# SpringMVC and Mybatis can't run 'insert'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-generator

When I click submit in localhost:8080/myregister.jsp(controller: 
localhost:8080/user/register),it gets:

Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): 
com.cn.hnust.dao.UserMapper.insert

When I click submit in localhost:8080/login.jsp,(controller: localhost:8080/user/login),it works.

[MYSQL:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_t`;
CREATE TABLE `user_t` (
  `username` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

]

I use mybatis-generator-core-1.3.2 to general UserMapper.xml,but why only the 'insert' function can't run?

The whole Maven project is in github:https://github.com/Bonsen/Spring-SpringMVC-mybatis.

Comment: The exception should have line numbers, so that will tell you where it's trying to use the statement, and that should tell you what it isn't finding, that should get you at least part way to a solution. Also, edit your post to format the code like code (click the {} icon).

Comment: Sorry，I'm careless.All codes are in github.When I run it and click the only 'submit' button of myregister.jsp on tomcat, the form of  myregister.jsp will throw something wrong.

Comment: It said:"org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.cn.hnust.dao.UserMapper.insert ,at com.cn.hnust.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.insert(UserServiceImpl.java:30)
at com.cn.hnust.controller.UserController.toIndex(UserController.java:39)

Comment: @blm ,UserServiceImpl.java:30 is:public int insert(User user) {
  this.usermapper.insert(user);//this!!!!
  return 0;
},UserController.java:39 is: @RequestMapping(value = "/register",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String toIndex(@RequestParam(value="username") String username,@RequestParam(value="password") String password,Model model){.............
user.setUsername(username);user.setPassword(password);
   this.userService.insert(user);//this!!!!
   model.addAttribute("user", user);}return SUCCESS;  }